# ggts won't register click or key press

Tags: ggts

i have been happily coding a grails project on ggts on mac os sierra 10.12 until a few days ago. a botched minikube install made ggts stop working. ide would start but no click or keypress would register , it was not usable.

i took this opportunity to reinstall os to first monterey 12 , then to mojave 10.14 , which seemed to demand less from hardware.

my problem persisted , ggts would start , ask for workspace directory but no click or keypress is working.

i tried jdk 8 66/202/221.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out APFS filesystem should be case insensitive for ggts to work. Reinstalling OS ( mojave ) did the trick.